# Ternary operator array sort check. Having trouble understanding what does it to

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, conditional-operator

Can you guys help me understand how does this code check if inputed array sorted by ascending, descending or not sorted at all? I tried to understand it myself for two days but with no success

Here is the code

```
const arraySortInfo = (inputArray) => {
  if (inputArray.some((element) => typeof element !== "number")) {
    return "Some elements are not numbers";
  }

  if (
    inputArray.every((element, index) =>
      index > 0 ? element >= inputArray[index - 1] : true
    )
  ) {
    return "Array sorted by ascending";
  }

  if (
    inputArray.every((element, index) =>
      index > 0 ? element <= inputArray[index - 1] : true
    )
  ) {
    return "Array sorted by descending";
  }

  return "Array isn't sorted";
};

const a = [5, "abc", 10, 1];
const b = [4, 10, 14, 25, 25, 50];
const c = [150, 132, 80, 40];
const d = [15, 26, 10, 23, 85];
```

I specifically lost in this lines of code and the same one for descending

```
if (
    inputArray.every((element, index) =>
      index > 0 ? element >= inputArray[index - 1] : true
    )
  ) {
    return "Array sorted by ascending";
  }
```

I tried to sit and write down everything on paper but so far I thought that I understood what it does with ascending, but then I tried to figure out descending check the same way and it didn't add up so I must be wrong at something.

Here is how I understand it on ascending example

```
inputArray[4, 7, 10 for example].every((element, index) =>
 first time     index 0 > 0 ? element 4 >= inputArray*//4,7,10 = 2 indexes//*[index */0/* - 1] : true
 *so if 4 >= 1 it return true*
 second time    index > 0 ? element 7  >= inputArray*//4,7,10 = 2 indexes//*[index */1/* - 1] : true
 *if 7 >= 2 returns true*
 third time     index > 0 ? element 10 >= inputArray*//4,7,10 = 2 indexes//*[index */2/* - 1] : true
 *if 10 >= 1 return true*
*and if every time this was true it will return "Array sorted by ascending"*
```

It worked here for me. But it didn't work the same way for descending numbers so I must be wrong. Maybe I'm wrong about (element, index) inputs?

Comment: For ascending, it checks whether every element is `>=` the previous element. For descending, it checks whether every element is `<=` the previous element. No mystery here... Admittedly, skipping the elements at index 0 with a ternary operator is a little opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
inputArray.every((element, index) =>
  index > 0 ? element >= inputArray[index - 1] : true
)
```

In plain English, this says: If we're looking at any item in the array (other than the first item), check that it is at least as large as the prior item in the array. There is a special case where we're at index=0, where we don't yet have a prior index to check against, and so we want to return 'true' in order to not cause the .every() check to fail in that particular case.

It could also have been written as:

```js
inputArray.slice(1).every((element, index) => element >= inputArray[(index])
```

Now, there is no need to check whether we are the first element, because slice(1) causes us to only encounter the second element onwards. Note that when we're at index 0 in the sliced array, element  will be the first item in the sliced array, but the second element in the original array. Conveniently, index=0 on the original array will be the element prior to the element at index=0 in the sliced array.

Comment: Ah I see now what `element >= inputArray[index - 1]` does. Seems like I didn't get it at all and overcomplicated it. Thank you!

By the way, how does function know where to take (element, index) from if we don't write it dirrectly?

Comment: @Celeron The 'every' method requires us to pass a function to it, which 'every' will call for each element in the array, and will pass (element, index) as parameters. It sounds like you may need to get more comfortable with arrow functions